# Any tips for good migration automation software?

Tags: java, build, automation, migration, continuous-integration

I'm in charge of a portion of a large software development project.  We have multiple environments (dev,test,pre-prod,prod, etc.) and many different software components.  Most of them are based on Java/Weblogic (with a smattering of other application servers thrown in).

We currently have no good way to migrate configuration & application code from environment to environment. Code is checked into an SCM. To perform a migration someone checks it out and manually migrates it. This is obviously lengthy and very error prone - mistakes happen all the time.

Does anyone have experience with migration tools that they might be able to share?  We don't mind doing scripting (obviously) but some sort of GUI to make this easy, along with a head start for situations like environment-specific config, would really help.

Comment: Apologies - I should have made this more clear:  Migration from one environment to a fairly similar, but other environment - App server A in dev -> SCM -> App Server A in test.

Comment: It's difficult without knowing specifics to help here, but note that GUIs do not always make this process less difficult. Are you looking for something like Hudson or Rundeck? Usually in situations like this configurations are kept separately for each environment and scripts provide symlinking to the correct config when a build is performed.

Comment: Consider editing tags to include [tag:Continuous-integration].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have all settings in property-files (one for dev, one for test etc). After it prepare deployment scripts (sh, ant, etc) that will take environment as a parameter and build/deploy the whole distributive with correct property file. Now when you have an automated way to do it you can setup jobs in any CI system (like Hudson) to run them using single click.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a good system to manage all of this - I understand that I could write scripts for all of this, but surely somebody, somewhere has faced this issue before.  Fundamentally, migrating code versions (and artifacts) through environments should be a common task... I'll look at Hudson etc, but I'd really like an easy deployment architecture.